# Use specific theme [not template file] for 404 and 403 generated for specific path

Tags: theming, 9, event-subscribers, 10, theme-negotiation

I have 2 themes, both enabled, assume they are called `my_first_theme` (default) and `my_second_theme`. I have `/whatever` path and lots of the pages under this path, and I have a theme negotiator, which sets `my_second_theme` as an active one for any page under this `/whatever` path, including nodes, views, custom controllers etc.

So far it works good.
Problem is, when 404 or 403 is triggered, the theme used to generate the response is always the default one (`my_first_theme`).

What I need is when 404 or 403 response is generated for any path under `/whatever` path, I would like the `my_second_theme` to be used for those templates, not the default one. The only way to achieve it at this moment I see is that I create a copy of the frontend stuff under `my_first_theme` just to be used for 404 and 403 purposes, but that's definitely a dirty way to do that. Basically I will have a clone of `my_second_theme` assets under the `my_first_theme` folder just to serve 404 and 403 responses.

Few examples of what I would like to achieve:

- `/nonexistent404` - `my_first_theme` used
- `/exists/but/access/denied403` - `my_first_theme` used
- `/whatever/nonexistent404` - `my_second_theme` used
- `/whatever/path/exists/but/no/access403` - `my_second_theme` used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does the theme negotiator get the path?

In a sub-request for a 403/404 error page you are probably looking for the path of the main request:

```
$main_request = \Drupal::requestStack()->getMainRequest();
$path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath($main_request);
```

Comment: Unfortunately by the time the 404 error is handled, Drupal has already completed the theme negotiation process and set the active theme. This is why the theme negotiator does not affect the theme for 404 pages. I also tried to handle KernelEvents::EXCEPTION, without any luck, theme is already chosed by that time

Comment: Did you try to get the path I suggested in applies() and determineActiveTheme() of your theme negotiator? I just tested it with my debugger and it stops there in the sub-request.

Comment: Looking at the theme manager this service is global to the main request so it doesn't really matter when the theme is initialized. Important for a path-based theme negotiator is to get the path this way. Then you don't depend on the timeline. However, for a 404 this is very likely to take place in the sub-request because you are thrown out of the main request very early before any theming can happen.

Comment: Okay so basically getMainRequest() is what I needed. Before that I was using $route_match, which was only working for existing routes and in case of 404/403 it was an instance of NullRouteMatch. Thanks for your help.